# Only 20 items returned in Tasks.Tasklists.list

Tags: google-apps-script

Following google apps script returns 20. I have far more than 20 Tasklist

```
 tasklist = Tasks.Tasklists.list().getItems();
 l = tasklist.length;
 Logger.log(l);
```

Is there a limit on the number of returned items?

Another try: with maxresults on 100 returns again 20 lists

```
function listTaskLists() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    maxResults: 100
  };
  var response = Tasks.Tasklists.list(optionalArgs);
  var taskLists = response.items;
  if (taskLists && taskLists.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Task lists:');
    for (var i = 0; i < taskLists.length; i++) {
      var taskList = taskLists[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', taskList.title, taskList.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No task lists found.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Retrieving all of your tasks in all of your task lists

This might be of some help to you.  I've been working on it much of the day trying to figure out how the page tokens work and I created ten tasks in each of 35 task lists (programmatically) and I've finally started to see iterations get above one.  So this is a pretty good way to get your tasks I think and I have to thank @tehhowch for giving me the start that I needed to get this running.

```
function listTasks() {
  var taskToken;
  var iteration=0;
  var opts={pageToken:taskToken,maxResults:100};
  do{
    iteration++;
    var myLists=Tasks.Tasklists.list(opts)
    if(myLists.items){
      for(var i=0;i<myLists.items.length;i++){
        var item=myLists.items[i];
        Logger.log(item.title + '\n' + item.id + '\n');
        var myTasks=Tasks.Tasks.list(item.id)
        if(myTasks.items){
          for(var j=0;j<myTasks.items.length;j++){
            Logger.log(myTasks.items[j].title + '\n');
          }
        }else{
          Logger.log('No tasks for ' + item.title + '\n');
        }
      }
    }
    Logger.log('Get Page Token ' + 'Iterations: ' + iteration);
    opts.pageToken=myLists.nextPageToken;
  }while(opts.pageToken);
  Logger.log('End of Function');
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. But why is this so complicated just to get a simple list? Does this means that the default maxresults=20?

Comment: I suppose that if there are more than 20 tasks in a taskslist that we run into the same problem?

Comment: I did a test and even if there are more than 20 tasks in a tasklist, the program works correctly!

Comment: Default maxResults does appear to be 20 for lists.  But it''s much higher for tasks.  Greater than 99. But I think the usefulness of maxResults comes into play when you want to display them in a UI.  It gives the developer the ability to set a limit on how big each chunk of data is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set maxResults option?

```
function test() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    maxResults: 25
  };  
  var tasklist = Tasks.Tasklists.list().getItems(optionalArgs);
  var l = tasklist.length;
  Logger.log(l);
}
```